# glUniformLocation returns -1

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math, uniform

I'm trying to uniform a model matrix into a vertex shader using

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "modelMatrix"),
    1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(objmesh[0]->modelMatrix));
```

but when I use this, the model does not show. I've used

```
int location = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "modelMatrix");
```

to find the location but it only returns -1. I've also tried using a manually made matrix (as an identity matrix) in the vertex shader and when I do that it works. I've done this exact thing to another shader, just a different program.

objmesh is just a std::vector that contains a struct with a mesh's vertices, uvs and so fourth. As of now, the modelMatrix is just an identity matrix.

I uniform the matrix in the vertex shader like so: `uniform mat4 modelMatrix;`

Comment: Post the full vertex shader source code.

Comment: I found the problem. Posted it in the Answer section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: I accidentally used glGetAttribLocation instead of glGetUniformLocation